# Could not centralise the google map after location search in angular 2

Tags: google-maps, angular

I have a input field and a button. On click of button the location whatever written in the input field will set a marker in google map. I am able to locate a marker in map. But it wont appear in the centre. In fact map will stay constant whatever the location you search.

```
getAddress(place:Object) { 
    this.markers = [];
    var address = this.step1Data.map_address;
    if (!address) return false;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var that = this;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            var lat =  location.lat();
            var lng = location.lng();
            that.markers.push({
                lat: lat,
                lng: lng,
                label: 'A',
                draggable: false
            })
            that._googleMapsApi.setCenter(location);
        } 
    });
}
```

setCenter() method is not working here. May I know the reason. googleMapsApi is imported from angular2-google-maps/core.

Comment: That probably depends on the parent element. What is `display` and `position` set to of the parent element (host of the map element)?

Comment: zoom: number = 10;
  
 lat: number = 40.4278841;
 lng: number = -74.415984; [disableDefaultUI]="true"
         [zoomControl]="true"
         [disableDefaultUI]="false"